# Use another theme (postmark) with compodoc

Tags: compodoc

I would like to use the postmark theme with compodoc (https://compodoc.github.io/website/guides/themes.html).

However, it does not work!
I have already tried

```
npm run doc:buildandserve --theme Postmark

npm run compodoc --theme postmark
```

I get the error **Provided source folder postmark was not found in the current directory**

Do I have to download the theme? Where do I find it?

Answer (score 1):

I may be late in answering this.  I just tried it today and it was working. Try the following command in Terminal of the project directory

```
compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json --theme postmark
```

And this will be the result

[image]

Method 2: If you are using script task in your package.json

[image]

command:

> "compodoc": "npx compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json --theme postmark -n
>   \"Project Name\""

Hope this help.